# XCode copies only changed xib files to the target binary

Tags: xcode6, xib

In my project I have almost 30 xib files located in an en.lproj folder and henced listed as english localization in XCode. When I compile my project, however, these xib files are not copied to the target folder (Resources/en.lproj) unless I modify them. All other resources are always copied, regardless of their change state. Of course all the xib files are in the "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase (along with a lot of other resources like images).

This behavior gives me some trouble, e.g. when I manually remove the .app from the DerivedData folder. The app is rebuilt completely on next build in XCode, only the xibs are all missing until I touch all of them.

How can I solve this problem and make XCode always copy my xib files too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to have been fixed with one of the latest XCode versions. I just checked with XCode 7.1.1 and the nibs are copied regardless of their change status, if they don't exist in the target folder already.